# Efeito de delay indesejado

Tags: javascript, html, css, animação

**Problema:** A animação do menu desktop e logo está com atraso indesejado (+ ou - 3s), porém o ícone do menu mobile funciona como esperado

**Tentativas:**

```
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-delay: none;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-delay: none;
```

Também tentei com `!important`

**Código:** http://commandinvest.com é um template que peguei na internet [Cube](https://freehtml5.co/preview/?item=cube-free-html5-bootstrap-website-template)

Comment: Guilherme qual animação mais precisamente? Essa logo e texto "Segurança e rentabilidade" que está sobe a imagem logo no início da página?

Comment: @hugocsl a animação do tamanho do menu, que diminui ao rolar a página para baixo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está nessa classe no arquivo `css.css` Ele está afetando alguns elementos dentro da sua `.gtco-nav`

```
* {
    transition: 0.5s !important;
    transition-timing-function: linear !important;
}
```

Esse `transition: 0.5s !important` está fazendo esse "delay" na transição. Se vc colocar 0s no lugar do 0.5s, vc vai ver que resolve. Porem como está no seletor universal **`*`** vc vai ter que ver a melhor forma de contornar isso para não perder o efeito onde não quer.

**OBS:** O seletor **`*`** tem um tempo de performe péssimo por isso deve parecer mais do que 0.5s, esse é o pior seletor quando o CSS tem que ler o arquivo todo para colocar a classe. Lei mais aqui http://gabsferreira.com/eficiencia-dos-seletores-css/

Comment: Eu retirei e funcionou no tempo certo. Mas o `transition` não serve para fazer com que o efeito seja suave?

Comment: É tipo isso, na verdade ele é o tempo que a animação vai demorar para ir do 0 ao 100% (é o tempo que ela demora pra ir do inicio ao fim). Eu não sei ao certo pq ela esta afetando dessa forma, mas podem ter outros elementos interagindo nisso. E o seletor " * " tb prejudica a performance. Repare que no seu style.css tem vários elementos com transition, todos que estão dentro da navbar podem estar interferindo nisso nesse atraso...

Comment: Eu tirei o efeito do `*` e coloquei apenas nos lugares que quero, mas a imgem (logo) ainda fica com esse atraso em relação aos demais itens do menu, tem alguma dica?

Comment: Sim `todos os seus `<a>` inclusive o que envolve a logo, e a imagem da logo ainda estão com transition...